# Вопрос по ng-repeat="phone in phones" из учебника

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Вот стандартный код из учебника

```
  <div ng-app="phonecatApp">
      <ul ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
          <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'Samsung S5™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}  
  ];
});
```

Подскажите, откуда берётся название ng-repeat? (я имею ввиду "phone in phones" - если его убрать или модифицироватть то приложение ломается, почему?)

Comment: А вы не задавились вопросом откуда берутся директивы `ng-app`, `ng-controller`? Системные директивы данного фреймворка, о которых вы можете почитать в [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive).

Comment: @romeo да, это системные директивы, а phone in phones мне кажеться не совсем системная

Comment: Это expression в понимании angular. Angular работает по принципу двунаправленного биндинга. Как только появляются новые данные в переменной `phones` происходит выполнение выражания, в данном случае цикла. Думаю, вам ещё рано хвататься за такого монстра, ибо даже опытные разработчики испытывают боль, когда сталкиваются с Angular 1.x. Нужно время и терпение.

Comment: [Про боль](http://habrahabr.ru/post/246905/)

Comment: @romeo спасибо, примерно понял, сложная штука какая то. Рано хвататься? Ну а за что тогда - js - не профи, но что то пишу, jq тоже, вот теперь пытаюсь за фреймворк взяться. т.к. хотел бы перейти на должность js или frontend разработчика, а во всех вакансия указана необходимость знания сего

Comment: если у вас был неплохой задел хотя бы на том же jq, то подобных вопросов у вас не возникло (про Angular). Вокруг Angular много шума. Возможно, из-за google, под крылом у которого он разрабатывается, но при этом ни в одном из сервисов не используется. Для Angular уже множество библиотек написано. Чувствуется стремеление покрыть всё то, что уже сделано на jquery. Любая популярная библиотека имеет альтернативу на нативном angular. Взять хотя бы [bootstrap ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) С поиском готовых решений для какого-нибудь Knockout будет гораздо сложнее.

Comment: На клиенте нужно стремится минимизировать код, а потому, если выбрал angular-way или иной фреймворк-way, то стоит полностью отказаться от jquery. Есть надежда, что Angular 2.0 будет дружелюбней и проще.

Comment: @romeo знания jq у меня есть, с опытом проблемы, а с этим примером лопухнулся - просто не додумал что это цикл

Comment: Если jquery указывал разработчику писать селекторы в js-файлах, то angular нас возвращает к истокам - к декларативный/инлайновому стилю, т.е. писать прямо в вёрстке, но при этом стараться выносить сложную логику в js-файл (в контроллеры/директивы). Нужно уметь чувствовать баланс, чтобы не "засрать" html избыточными конструкциями, которые в последствии будет сложно прочитать даже тебе. Вот так и живём.

Comment: Кроме того, все js-фреймворки подталкивают разработчика использовать [SPA-подход](https://goo.gl/bWsJrL) - [pushState](https://goo.gl/ewynBu) + вся шаблонизация на клиенте, от сервера ждут только json. Привет поисковым краулерам! Читал, что google умеет вполне себе сносно парсить js, а вот про yandex и иных товарищей-вендоров не слышал. В общем, костыль-way с PhantomJS или [иными](https://prerender.io/) инструментами. Изоморфность в связке с PHP или иным серверным языком, кроме NodeJS, как-то сомнительна.